# Inverted pyramid caption, but table not centered

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions, threeparttable

I have managed to hack together a solution to the perennial "My university requires inverted pyramid style captions" problem. However, it isn't complete. I can make the captions inverted pyramid, and I can make them scale with the table width (also a requirement). However, if the table is narrower than the minimum caption width, the table is no longer centered below the caption.

I use the caption package to define a custom justification (InvertedPyramid). threeparttable redefines \linewidth to match the current table, which is how the InvertedPyramid justification scales. Setting the TPTminimum to 3 inches keeps the captions of narrow tables from looking ridiculous. However, when the table is narrower than 3 inches it is no longer centered beneath the caption. I've tried the \makebox solution but that resulted in errors.

In my MWE I have a lot of packages that aren't strictly necessary for the MWE, but anything I use to solve this problem needs to not conflict with these packages (at least, it should conflict with as few as possible).

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}            
\usepackage{amssymb}                
\usepackage{graphicx}      
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[calcwidth = \columnwidth]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable}
\usepackage{subcaption}                 
\usepackage{setspace}       
\usepackage{epstopdf}           
\usepackage{cite}       
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{float}  
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}
\DeclareCaptionJustification{InvertedPyramid}{\hsize=\linewidth
                \parindent=0pt
                \leftskip=0pt plus.5fil
                \rightskip=0pt plus-0.5fil
                \parfillskip=0pt plus1fil
                \emergencystretch=1in
                \parshape10
                0.00in \linewidth
                0.025\linewidth 0.95\linewidth
                0.05\linewidth 0.9\linewidth
                0.075\linewidth 0.85\linewidth
                0.1\linewidth 0.8\linewidth
                0.125\linewidth 0.75\linewidth
         0.15\linewidth 0.70\linewidth
         0.175\linewidth 0.65\linewidth
         0.2\linewidth 0.60\linewidth
         0.225\linewidth 0.55\linewidth
                \strut
    } 
\renewcommand{\TPTminimum}{3in}
\captionsetup[table]{justification=InvertedPyramid} 

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[b!]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption[Values of the $\beta_i$ coefficients to describe the stiffness of lattice-flexured CAFPs.]{Values of the $\beta_i$ coefficients used in an Equation, and $R^2$ values for each set of coefficients. These coefficients are used to describe the stiffness of X-type and V-type lattice flexures subjected to lateral loads.}
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
& X-type & V-type \\
\hline
\hline
$\beta_1$ & -0.2263 & -0.2280 \\ %updated
$\beta_2$ & -0.0911 & -0.0541 \\
$\beta_3$ & 2.0862 & 2.0502 \\
$\beta_4$ & -0.0031 & -0.0027 \\
$\beta_5$ & -0.0029 & -0.0026 \\
$R^2$ & 0.9949 & 0.9964 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:betas}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does pretty much the same thing as `threepartable`, except that the centering `\hfil` is outside the box instead of inside.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}            
\usepackage{amssymb}                
\usepackage{graphicx}      
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[calcwidth = \columnwidth]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable}
\usepackage{subcaption}                 
\usepackage{setspace}       
\usepackage{epstopdf}           
\usepackage{cite}       
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{float}  
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}
\DeclareCaptionJustification{InvertedPyramid}{\hsize=\linewidth
                \parindent=0pt
                \leftskip=0pt plus.5fil
                \rightskip=0pt plus-0.5fil
                \parfillskip=0pt plus1fil
                \emergencystretch=1in
                \parshape10
                0.00in \linewidth
                0.025\linewidth 0.95\linewidth
                0.05\linewidth 0.9\linewidth
                0.075\linewidth 0.85\linewidth
                0.1\linewidth 0.8\linewidth
                0.125\linewidth 0.75\linewidth
         0.15\linewidth 0.70\linewidth
         0.175\linewidth 0.65\linewidth
         0.2\linewidth 0.60\linewidth
         0.225\linewidth 0.55\linewidth
                \strut
    } 
\renewcommand{\TPTminimum}{3in}
\captionsetup[table]{justification=InvertedPyramid} 

\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\newlength{\tempwidth}
\usepackage{showframe}% to check centering only

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[b!]
% calculate size of tabular
\savebox{\tempbox}{\begin{tabular}{lcr}
& X-type & V-type \\
\hline
\hline
$\beta_1$ & -0.2263 & -0.2280 \\ %updated
$\beta_2$ & -0.0911 & -0.0541 \\
$\beta_3$ & 2.0862 & 2.0502 \\
$\beta_4$ & -0.0031 & -0.0027 \\
$\beta_5$ & -0.0029 & -0.0026 \\
$R^2$ & 0.9949 & 0.9964 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
% set width
\ifdim\wd\tempbox<\TPTminimum\relax \tempwidth=\TPTminimum\relax
\else\tempwidth=\wd\tempbox
\fi
% format
\hfil\begin{minipage}{\tempwidth}
\caption[Values of the $\beta_i$ coefficients to describe the stiffness of lattice-flexured CAFPs.]{Values of the $\beta_i$ coefficients used in an Equation, and $R^2$ values for each set of coefficients. These coefficients are used to describe the stiffness of X-type and V-type lattice flexures subjected to lateral loads.}
\label{tab:betas}
\hfil\usebox{\tempbox}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: This almost does the trick - the one thing I changed was I used \centering in the minipage instead of \hfil because this keeps both the caption and the table centered on the page, instead of centered on each other but offset from the page center. Many thanks!